# Replace html encoded characters in Java

Tags: java, html, stringescapeutils

I want to convert the string `<p>&uuml;&egrave;</p>` to `<p>üé</p>`, but both `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()` (from `org.apache.commons.text`) and `HtmlUtils.unescapeHtml()` (from `org.springframework.web.util`) convert it to `&lt;p&gt;üè&lt;/p&gt;`. Is there a way to keep existing html tags intact?

Comment: `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("<p>&uuml;&egrave;</p>")` returned `<p>üè</p>` for me.

Comment: Both work fine for me. The output you mention is escaped rather then unescaped.

Comment: You're right, it works. The problem was that I put the result in a html document, which of course has to encode it again, so it looked like that function didn't work.